# running shell script within shell script in a nested for loop

Tags: shell, scripting, loops

hi everyone I've got a simple script which executes another script in a nested for loop

my problem is that while the double for loop is executing fine without the addition of the script which needs to be run at each iteration, if i add the script the execution only happens once.

any ideas why?

```
for ((i = 0; i<10; i++))
do  
echo "outer forloop $i"
for ((j = 0; j<6; j++))
do
    exec ./run.sh
    done
done
```

thanks
andreas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exec replaces the current process with a new process. Use `./run.sh`